# Line break between multiple buttons in one piece of code

Tags: python, html, css

So I am working on a blog. I needed to have some space between these buttons and I want the first letter to be capital.

I would have been able to do it if the code was like this:

```
<button id="buttonOne"> click one me </button> 
<br>
<button id="buttonTwo"> click on me too </button>
```

But my code is this:

```
{% for item in cat_menu_list %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><h4><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item%}">{{ item }}</a></button>

            </div>
```

I hope you can help me. Do I also need to make another file for example button.css and then import it in the HTML file.

Comment: apply css to `button.btn.btn-info` elements, you can give it margin top and bottom, or use flexbox with gap, or grid with gap on your form

Comment: @Beki Can you please give me a sample of how to do it because I don't really understand. Also do I need to make a new file and then import it to HTML. Thanks..

Comment: reset display to block with margins ?  try `button {display:block;margin:0.5em;}`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I get it but where do I apply it.

Comment: in your css file if you have any yet.

Comment: Hi @G-Cyrillus I don't though.

Comment: I created a CSS file called button.css then I typed the code and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By resetting the display to block with margins as G-Cyrillus said it worked.

G-Cyrillus way:

```
{display:block;margin:0.5em;}
```

I just needed to tinker it a bit like this:

```
    {% for item in cat_menu_list %}
    <style>
        button {
            display:block;
            margin:0.5em;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><h4><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item%}">{{ item }}</a></button>

    </div>
      

    {% endfor %}
```

If you are wondering how it turned out here is a picture of it below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIe3h.png

Comment: great, you found your way ! you can select your own answer as the solution btw.

Comment: Hi @G-Cyrillus, Thanks, I would but for some reason it is not letting me and says accept this answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

```
button::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

For first letter capital.

Answer (score 0):

```
button::first-letter { font-size: xx-large; color: #ff0000 }
```

For first letter capital using font-size attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some space to button put more br or use padding-bottom: px; if you put a css code in first button and use padding-top:px if you put a css code in second button.

it depends to you how many px you put. example 50px

You can also use transform:translateY("put value in px,em,cm,mm etcc here")